# How to initialize a mysqli variable when database is not yet created

Tags: php, database, mysqli, database-connection

I am using `mysqli` inorder to use database functionality in PHP. So, when I use new `mysqli(.,.,.,.,db_name)`, I need to mention `db_name` in the begining. I want to create a db after opening a connection. So, obviously I wont be able to give `db_name` value while initializing. So, how to initialize a `mysqli` variable using which I can create a database `$mysqli->query("create database Sample")`, for example.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","1sdfd6","Sample","3306");
//How can i provide Sample here when i am creating sample in next statement

$mysqli->query("create database Sample");                               
$mysqli->select_db("Sample");
```

Comment: you shouldn't create a database after connect. It have to be be already created

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php.

The database parameter (just like all the other parameters the mysqli constructor) is optional.

Though perhaps you should reconsider your plan of attack?

Comment: I would love to know why this answer got down voted.

Comment: so if i dont want to enter the db name should i send null?? as in
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","ewdsdsds","","3306");

Comment: Yes, leaving it as an empty string (different than `NULL`!) will do the trick. Though I'm not sure if creating databases like this is a good idea.